# Separating party of a text file to organize the text to get total numbers

Tags: java

I cannot figure out how to separate the ranks of the professors to add the salaries this is from the following question:

> **Process large dataset** A university posts its employees’ salaries at
>   http://cs.armstrong.edu/liang/data/Salary.txt. Each line in the file
>   consists of a faculty member’s first name, last name, rank, and salary
>   (see Programming Exercise
>   12.24). Write a program to display the total salary for assistant professors, associate professors, full professors, and all faculty,
>   respectively, and display the average salary for assistant professors,
>   associate professors, full professors, and all faculty, respectively.

A sample of the input:

```
FirstName1 LastName1 assistant 79174.73
FirstName2 LastName2 associate 70817.75
FirstName3 LastName3 associate 69619.0
FirstName4 LastName4 full 116992.43
FirstName5 LastName5 full 116761.76
FirstName6 LastName6 full 123743.86
FirstName7 LastName7 assistant 70071.81
FirstName8 LastName8 assistant 67605.92
FirstName9 LastName9 associate 65534.42
```

My code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Faculty implements Comparable<Faculty> {
    public String FirstName;
    public String LastName;
    public double salary;
    public String rank;

    Faculty() {
    }

    Faculty(String FirstName, String LastName, double salary) {
        setFirst(FirstName);
        setLast(LastName);
        setSalary(salary);
    }

    public void setFirst(String FirstName) {
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
    }

    public String getFirst() {
        return FirstName;
    }

    public void setLast(String LastName) {
        this.LastName = LastName;
    }

    public String getLast() {
        return LastName;
    }

    public void setrank() {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public int getrank(String rank) {
        if (rank == "full")
            return 0;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public int compareTo(Faculty arg) {
        return Integer.compare(getrank(), arg.getrank());
    }
}

class associate extends Faculty {
    public String associate;

    associate() {
    }

    associate(String FirstName, String LastName, String associate, double salary) {
        super(FirstName, LastName, salary);

    }

    public void setAssociate(String associate) {
        this.associate = associate;
    }

    public String getAssociate() {
        return associate;
    }

    public String compareTo(Faculty arg) {
        return String.compare(getRank(), arg.getRank());
    }
}

class assistant extends Faculty {
    public String assistant;

    assistant() {
    }

    assistant(String FirstName, String LastName, String assistant, double salary) {
        super(FirstName, LastName, salary);
        getAssistant = assistant;
    }

    public void setAssistant(String assistant) {
        this.assistant = assistant;
    }

    public String getAssistant() {
        return assistant;
    }

    public String compareTo(Faculty arg) {
        return String.compare(getRank(), arg.getRank());
    }
}

class full extends Faculty {
    public String full;

    full() {
    }

    full(String FirstName, String LastName, String full, double salary) {
        super(FirstName, LastName, salary);
        getFull = full;
    }

    public void setFull(String full) {
        this.full = full;
    }

    public String getFull() {
        return full;
    }

    public String compareTo(Faculty arg) {
        return String.compare(getRank(), arg.getRank());
    }
}

public class Facmembers {
    Faculty[] fm;

    //input
    public void input() throws FileNotFoundException {
        int count = 0;
        Scanner input = null;
        try {
            input = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/Fava/Desktop/cps 2231 notes"));
            if (input.hasNextLine()) {
                count = input.nextInt();
            }
            fm = new Faculty[count];
            for (int i = 0; i < count && input.hasNextLine(); i++) {
                Faculty fm;
                String FirstName = input.next();
                String LastName = input.next();
                String ranks = input.next();
                if (rank(ranks)) {
                    ranktype(ranks);
                }
                double salary = input.nextDouble();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            if (input != null) {
                System.out.println("File not found.");
                input.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean rank(String A) {
        String test = A.toLowerCase();
        if (test == "full" || test == "associate" || test = "assistant") {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static String ranktype(Faculty mem) {
        if (rank(mem.getrank()) == true) {
            return mem.getrank();
        } else {
            return "Error in rank";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean separate the ranks of professors? We don't know how they are ranked without more information. Can you provide us a sample of the text file and describe what you mean by "ranks"?

Comment: Import the data into a SQL database. You will get all the required analysis using simple SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't tell us if your code works or if you have any problems with it, I try to give you the easiest solution to **solve the problem** that I can think of.

Use [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/):

```
sqlite> create table salary (firstname, lastname, role, amount);
sqlite> .separator " "
sqlite> .import Salary.txt salary
sqlite> select sum(amount) from salary where role = 'assistant';
20246511.91
sqlite> select sum(amount) from salary where role = 'associate';
28844146.58
sqlite> select sum(amount) from salary where role = 'full';
35678051.41
sqlite> select avg(amount) from salary where role = 'assistant';
65949.5501954398
sqlite> select avg(amount) from salary where role = 'associate';
83849.2633139535
sqlite> select avg(amount) from salary where role = 'full';
102229.373667622
```